# Can't use string ("Server1") as a SCALAR ref while "strict refs" in use

Tags: perl, class, struct, scalar

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
use strict;
use warnings;

use Class::Struct;

struct System => {
  Name => '$',
};

my $system = new System;
$system->Name("Server1");

my $strout1 = qq{Server is ${$system->Name}\n};
my $strout2 = "Server is \"".$system->Name."\"\n";

print $strout1;
print $strout2;
```

results in:

> Can't use string ("Server1") as a SCALAR ref while "strict refs" in
>   use at test.pl line 14.

I want to be able to use qq and deref `$system->Name` correctly.  Can anyone explain where i am going wrong?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Method calls aren't interpolated in double quoted strings, but dereferences are. If you want to interpolate the result of the method call, you must dereference a reference to it:

```
my $strout1 = qq{Server is ${\$system->Name}\n};
```

Comment: Typically `" @{[ $system->Name ]} "` is used instead

Answer (score 1):

Does the `Name` method really return a reference? Because this looks wrong:

```
${$system->Name}
```

That's dereferencing something, so I think should be written as simply `$system->Name`

You'll trigger the same error if you try:

```
print ${"Server1"};
```

Which suggests that you are actually getting a text string back.

Comment: It was the only way i could get the value to appear in any output.